# What is the meaning of these matrices in Perona & Malik filter

Tags: matlab, matrix

I was searching for the implementation of Perona & Malik filter in Matlab, when i found this [link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14995-anisotropic-diffusion--perona---malik-/content/anisodiff_Perona-Malik/anisodiff2D.m) "the link has an implementation for Perona and Malik filter using Matlab"

but there is the matrices that i didn't understand what is the use of them:

```
% 2D convolution masks - finite differences.
hN = [0 1 0; 0 -1 0; 0 0 0];
hS = [0 0 0; 0 -1 0; 0 1 0];
hE = [0 0 0; 0 -1 1; 0 0 0];
hW = [0 0 0; 1 -1 0; 0 0 0];
hNE = [0 0 1; 0 -1 0; 0 0 0];
hSE = [0 0 0; 0 -1 0; 0 0 1];
hSW = [0 0 0; 0 -1 0; 1 0 0];
hNW = [1 0 0; 0 -1 0; 0 0 0];
```

any one has an idea what are these matrices, or what do they mean?

Comment: Your URL is broken. Please edit the question to provide a working link – better yet, provide any vital information from the link in case the website goes away in the future.

Comment: @horchler Sorry for the mistake the link and the content has been edited

Answer (score 0):

These are the kernels for getting the gradients in **N**orth, **E**ast, **S**outh and **W**est directions, and also for dialgonals (NE = North East etc.).

```
hN = [0 1 0; 0 -1 0; 0 0 0];
```

or nicely formatted:

```
0  1  0
0 -1  0
0  0  0
```

Convolution of this kernel with an image yields the gradient in "North direction". Basically, this is a mask of factors that you apply to all your 3x3 areas of your image and since all except two entries are 0, what you get is the pixel at the top minus that in the center, thus the gradient in y-direction.